# Jump to right side of html page

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I have an HTML page with a big table and many columns, I need to scroll right of page automatically on page load.

I've tried this code but it doesn't work for me :

```
</script><script type="text/javascript">  
                               
   var myDiv = document.getElementById('containerDiv');
   myDiv.innerHTML = variableLongText;
   myDiv.scrollRight = 0;

</script>
```

Is it a correct approch to auto scroll the page?

Comment: You can use `window.scrollTo()` method to scroll to a particular set of coordinates in the document. See this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) for API.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any method to auto ZoomIn / ZoomOut the html page on page load too?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
                           
  var myDiv = document.getElementById('containerDiv');

  myDiv.scrollTo(0, myDiv.scrollRight)

</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
// Getting div from DOM
const myDiv = document.getElementById('containerDiv');

// Getting div's position 
divRect = myDiv.getBoundingClientRect();

// Scrolling to div's position
window.scrollTo({
  top: divRect.top,
  left: divRect.left,
  // behavior: 'smooth'
});

/* 
behavior: 'smooth' will give a smooth sensation with a slow transition on scroll. 
I would personally recommend using it (mainly if this is not intended to run on load).
*/
```

Better & without comments:

```
const divRect = document.getElementById('containerDiv').getBoundingClientRect();
window.scrollTo({ top: divRect.top, left: divRect.left });
```

For information about `getBoundingClientRect()`, check this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Answer (score 0):

if you want to scroll window then use

```
window.scrollTo(x-axis,y-axis);
```

or for specific div use

```
document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft += 10000;
```

so full program be like

```
window.onload = function() {
 // for specific div
  document.getElementById('nan').scrollLeft += 100000;
 
 //for window 
 /* window.scrollTo(10000, 0) */;
};
```

you can also see example
https://jsfiddle.net/zcmhp2de/38/

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        function zoom() {
            document.body.style.zoom = "300%" 
        }
</script>

<body onload="zoom()">
<h6>content</h6>
</body>
for zoom in zoom out you can use this one